# Повторяющееся метаописание

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Google search console пишет что на моем сайте по нескольким ссылкам идет повторяющееся метаописание из-за того что он почему-то видит ссылки как с параметрами так и без(ЧПУ):

```
http://site.ru/?menu=portfolio/gray
```

и

```
http://site.ru/portfolio/gray
```

вот настройки .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [QSA,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?menu=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Где я ошибся? Или что я сделал не так? Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Канонический адрес на страницах пропишите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это - врожденная болезнь ЧПУ реализованных через mod_rewrite. До тех пор, пока вы его используете - сделать видимым снаружи только 1 URL нормально не получится. Но, поскольку такая проблема возникла не только у вас - решение для нее давно уже придумали в самом гугле.

Самый простой вариант, который более не требует никаких настроек - обучить каждую страницу выдавать свой правильный URL в заголовке HTTP Link:

```
Link: <http://site.ru/portfolio/gray>; rel="canonical"
```

Это сделать довольно просто поскольку нужная часть адреса уже есть в параметре menu - а значит, нужный заголовок без проблем сформирует ваш `index.php`. Только надо не забыть сделать ей url-кодирование чтобы не получить HTTP Header Injection:

```
$path = implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $_GET['menu'])))
header("Link", "<http://site.ru/$path>; rel=\"canonical\"");
```

Полный список решений можно увидеть в их справочном центре по ссылке https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru.